# R Shiny: Side by Side Checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if its possible to display the check box option side by side on the UI. Some sample code that I've tried:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(   
    checkboxInput(inputId = "simOption", label = "Historical Data",value=TRUE),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "simOption2", label = "Historical Data 2",value=TRUE)


  ),

  mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(

  tabPanel("Heatmap",
           plotOutput("temp")
  ),
  tabPanel("About"),

  id="tabs"
)#tabsetPanel  

  )#mainPane;

))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try fudging some bootstrap syntax:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(   

    withTags(div(class='row-fluid',
                 div(class='span3', checkboxInput(inputId = "simOption", label = "Historical Data",value=TRUE)),
                 div(class='span5', checkboxInput(inputId = "simOption2", label = "Historical Data 2",value=TRUE))
    ))



  ),

  mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(

  tabPanel("Heatmap",
           plotOutput("temp")
  ),
  tabPanel("About"),

  id="tabs"
)#tabsetPanel  

  )#mainPane;

))
```

https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/99fdd6e46586

EDIT for horizontal radio button

from `?radiobutton`

```
radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
             c("Normal" = "norm",
               "Uniform" = "unif",
               "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
               "Exponential" = "exp"))
```

replace with a

```
 gsub("label class=\"radio\"", "label class=\"radio inline\"",radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
             c("Normal" = "norm",
               "Uniform" = "unif",
               "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
               "Exponential" = "exp")))
  )
```

Comment: I am new to bootstrap, but what if its a radio button in shiny? How can you apply the above framework? Radio button is rather trickier as its a single function as oppose to two separate ones. Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/649 alludes to maybe what you are describing. You can just build your own control using the basic tag building blocks.

Comment: Unless your very lazy like me in which case you can `gsub`

Answer (score 13):

You can use `checkboxGroupInput` with `inline = TRUE` param:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "simOption", label = "",
                   choices = c("Historical Data" = TRUE,
                               "Historical Data 2" = TRUE),
                   inline = TRUE)
```